# Mobile chrome button refresh action

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, reactjs

I've noticed that on mobile Chrome, any button whether it's in a form or not, automatically will trigger a page reload as a default action. This behavior doesn't happen on Safari or on desktop Chrome, buttons just act as buttons.

In some instances, this behavior is fine such as 1) navigating to a new page or 2) a network request, etc etc. However I have some `onClick` handlers that only scroll within the context of a single page and the page refresh causes that action to be lost. It seems like this is the default button behavior of mobile chrome and I haven't yet found a way to stop it.

I have a base react component for buttons that handles all the `onClick` events:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.props.onClick();
    return false;
 };

 render = () => {
    return (
      <button type="button" className={ this.props.className } style={ this.props.style } onClick={ this.handleClick }>{ this.props.title }</button>
   );
 };
```

Now it should stop the page from triggering a new request every time a button is pressed but unfortunately that's not the case. Is there something I'm missing as far as disabling the button default action?

Comment: Is your button inside a form? You could try handling the onSubmit and checking for the event.target. If event.target is of type 'button' then just return false to prevent the submit.

Comment: No, it's not. As I state, it's any button, regardless of if it's in a form.

Comment: Could you add a link to a test case in JSFiddle or similar? I could not find this problem in Google and I guess is something that should happen with any library and not only with React. Adding the `type="button"` attribute should be enough to prevent the behavior you describe.

Comment: I can't because the code is proprietary. But I found the bug. It actually has nothing to do with the button, it has to do with HTML5 History and chrome's support, which isn't great. I'm using React-Router and Redux-Simple-Router together and changing the url state causes a page refresh on mobile chrome.

Comment: Hey! Similiar problem here. Could you fix it? First I thought it has something to do with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212722/how-to-prevent-pull-down-to-refresh-of-mobile-chrome but after disabling pull down to refresh it still occures. And I don't even have a form on my page or any javascript or button that should refresh the page...