# How to prevent pull-down-to-refresh of mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile

I want to prevent pull-down-to-refresh of mobile chrome(especially iOS chrome). My web application has vertical panning event with device-width and device-height viewport, but whenever panning down, mobile chrome refreshes itself because of browser's default function. Plus, on Safari browser, screen is rolling during panning event. I want to disable these moves.

Of course, I tried event.preventDefault(); and touch-action: none; But it doesn't look work. Should I add eventListner and touch-action "on body tag"? I expect useful answer with example.

Comment: Add a minimal example code to get good answers

Comment: @Raju i found easy example code, here! thx >O<
http://output.jsbin.com/qofuwa/2/quiet

Comment: That's not what I meant.  Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: @Raju the post is self explatory. Adding code wouldn't have helped anyway. Pushing big words like MCVE doesnt improve your point. Dont be like that

Answer (score 57):

**For latest versions of Chrome:**

```
html,
body {
    overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}
```

**Old solution:**

*Since mobile Chrome >= 56 event listeners are passive by default and passive event listeners can't prevent defaults anymore.
[See here](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080)
You have to use active event listeners instead like so:*

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstartHandler, {passive: false});
document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchmoveHandler, {passive: false});
```

Comment: Wow, broke a ton of sites but yea, I see why they chose it. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Try this.

```
body {
  /* Disables pull-to-refresh but allows overscroll glow effects. */
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}
```

It worked well for me. I had weird scrolling issues due to other javascript hacks. Read this article for more details.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior

Comment: Yeah the hack I've posted doesn't seem to work anymore. This here works perfectly fine!

Comment: This work only on Chrome Android , not for Chrome IOs

Comment: Worked on these android browsers: opera and chrome

Answer (score 9):

Scroll behavior none works for me like this.

```
body {
    overscroll-behavior: none 
}
```

Comment: https://forum.framework7.io/t/how-to-disable-pull-to-refresh-in-android-chrome/10574

Answer (score 5):

The css-only answers posted here did not work for me. I ended up doing the following:

```
(function() {
    var touchStartHandler,
        touchMoveHandler,
        touchPoint;

    // Only needed for touch events on chrome.
    if ((window.chrome || navigator.userAgent.match("CriOS"))
        && "ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {

        touchStartHandler = function() {
            // Only need to handle single-touch cases
            touchPoint = event.touches.length === 1 ? event.touches[0].clientY : null;
        };

        touchMoveHandler = function(event) {
            var newTouchPoint;

            // Only need to handle single-touch cases
            if (event.touches.length !== 1) {
                touchPoint = null;

                return;
            }

            // We only need to defaultPrevent when scrolling up
            newTouchPoint = event.touches[0].clientY;
            if (newTouchPoint > touchPoint) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            touchPoint = newTouchPoint;
        };

        document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStartHandler, {
            passive: false
        });

        document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMoveHandler, {
            passive: false
        });

    }
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

For iOS I did the following for a single html page which expands to the size of the viewport. This solution doesn't allow any scrolling at all (which may not suit everyone, but worked well for me).

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```