# How to prevent pull to refresh in pwa - progressive web apps?

Tags: google-chrome-app, progressive-web-apps

as a progressive application is it not good to refresh application accidentally by pulling down the page.
is there any standard way (not css tricks) to disable refreshing entire page in PWA?

Comment: By CSS tricks you mean [overscroll-behavior-y: contain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212722/how-to-prevent-pull-down-to-refresh-of-mobile-chrome)?

Comment: @sadeghhp Did you find a solution?

Comment: using css tricks :D

Answer (score 20):

It works.

```css
body
{
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}
```

Comment: This no longer works on iOS. A working solution for me is on this page that addresses the iOS issue generally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69589919/2927114