# How to remove safari browser pull to refresh using react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I build an app using react native.when I am pulling page in safari browser to down , refresh loader is coming. I dont want pull to refresh loader in safari browser.Can anybody give any suggestions to remove the pull to refresh loader, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Would you provide some further information or consider marking my answer as correct @harinath-reddy

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73941939/1063714) to the problem which seems to work (at least as a patch).

To let react native profit from that, one could do the following (without being proud of what you've done):

```
export default function App(): ReactElement {
   // dirty patch to disable mobile safari p2r https://stackoverflow.com/a/70579685/1063714
   document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
   // ... your app specific code
   return (
        {/* ... Your application goes here */ }
   );
}
```