# R shiny mobile app: prevent PullToRefresh

Tags: android, css, r, mobile, shiny

**Context**: I am developing a mobile Shiny app using the [shinyMobile](https://rinterface.github.io/shinyMobile/) package, which is a wrapper for the famous framework7 HTML template.

In my app, the user has to make a selection of attributes on a first tab using multiple dropdown lists, and then, on the other tabs, some output is produced. Each tab requires the user to scroll up and down to access all the content and in this process, very often the 'pull to refresh' feature is triggered.

This is really annoying, because the entire attribute selection and output are lost, and the user has to start over from scratch.

**What I tried:** based on this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008194/disabling-androids-chrome-pull-down-to-refresh-feature) which pointed me to this Google developer [page](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior#disablp2r), I tried setting the CSS overscroll-behavior property to `contain` with: `body {overscroll-behavior-y: contain;}`. **PROBLEM:** It does not work for me! (tested on Chrome Android)

**Minimal reproducible example:**

default app, deployed [here](https://safetyapp.shinyapps.io/pulltorefresh_issue/)

```r
library(shiny);library(shinyMobile)
shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = f7Page(
    f7Card(
      h5('try to pull to refresh. normally it should work.')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

Supposedly fixed app, deployed [here](https://safetyapp.shinyapps.io/pulltorefresh_issue_fixed/)

```r
library(shiny);library(shinyMobile)
shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = f7Page(
    tags$style(type='text/css', '.body{overscroll-behavior-y: contain;}'),
    f7Card(
      h5('try to pull to refresh. Normally it should not work.')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

Hope you guys can reproduce my issue and identify what is amiss!!!

Comment: Your second link might not be up to date i think. It seems to be the same as the first.

Comment: Thank you! Just fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to change your css part to: `html,body{overscroll-behavior-y: contain;}`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42509310/3502164.

Then it works for me on my mobile (android chrome).

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMobile)
app <- shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = f7Page(
    tags$style(type='text/css', 'html,body{overscroll-behavior-y: contain;}'),
    f7Card(
      h5('try to pull to refresh. Normally it should not work.')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)

# use host config to access app from mobiles in the same network
shiny::runApp(appDir = app, host = '0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: did the trick for me, thanks much! I have to wait 16 hours before awarding the bounty

Comment: bounty awarded!