# How to prevent pull to refresh when draw on Canvas in Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I'm developing a webpage with HTML and JS. And there's a canvas in index.html.

```
...
</head>
<body>
...
    <canvas class="Wrapper vector-canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" style="width: 125px; 
     height: 95px;"></canvas>
...
</body>
```

I can draw on canvas using Chrome for PC. But can't not draw with my Android tablet.
This is what happen when I touch and move on canvas.
[image]
The pull to refresh icon was showed up.

How can I prevent this event when I touch the canvas?

Comment: [Disabling Pull Down Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008194/disabling-androids-chrome-pull-down-to-refresh-feature), [Prevent Pull Down Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212722/how-to-prevent-pull-down-to-refresh-of-mobile-chrome)  and [Overscroll Behavior](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior) These link might help